# How to save CZEC language data into sql server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have below line of CZEC language.

"V současné době se zabýváme bilancí našich **účtů**".

but when I insert this in database it's get converted automatic to "V soucasné dobe se zabýváme bilancí našich **úctu**."

so if you observed bold text is converted. I need to save the line as it is in database.

Table details:
Column type: varchar(max)

Comment: If you want to support the full unicode range of characters, use `nvarchar` rather than `varchar`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I have used **nvarchar** also still i'm getting same result.

Comment: Then you're also passing your string around as a string literal and not prefixing the literal with `N`. Ideally, if the string is coming from an application, put it in an `nvarchar` parameter. Otherwise, if this is a plain query, use the `N` prefix. `declare @t nvarchar(max)
set @t = 'V současné době se zabýváme bilancí našich účtů'
select @t
set @t = N'V současné době se zabýváme bilancí našich účtů'
select @t`

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks :) Resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks : Below is the answer

**declare** @t nvarchar(max) 
**set** @t = 'V současné době se zabýváme bilancí našich účtů' 
**select** @t 
**set** @t = N'V současné době se zabýváme bilancí našich účtů' 
**select** @t